# Is it possible to make ajax call from .ascx page. here is my code please review

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

This is from .ascx page, here i am calling .autocomplete inside this i am colling ajax call. please help.

```
$("#txtUsers").autocomplete({
    //source: availableTags
    source: function (request, response) {
        //Pass the selected country to the query manager to limit the selection to 1 country

        $.ajax({
            url: 'DietitianAppointment.ascx/GetNames',
            data: '{Name:' + $('#txtUsers').val() + '}',
            type: 'POST', // a jQuery ajax POST transmits in querystring format (key=value&key1=value1) in utf-8
            dataType: 'json', //return data in json format
            success: function (data) {
                response($.map(data, function (item) {
                    return {
                        label: item.stateName,
                        value: item.name
                        //abbrev: item.stateAbbrev
                    };
                }));
            }
        });
    }
});
```

on .cs page:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string GetNames(string Name)
{
    return "";
}
```

Comment: What should we review? Clarify your problem.

Comment: You cannot directly call an `.ascx` control, it simply won't work and IIS will throw an error.  You must make your `GetNames` method available via an `.aspx`, `.asmx`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Yes,
Since you have already define a method as [WebMethod] in your Cs
you can have your ajax call url like this..

```
url: "/DietitianAppointment.aspx/GetNames"
```

So Your Ajax Call would be like this...

```
 $.ajax({
   url: '/DietitianAppointment.aspx/GetNames',
   data: '{Name:' + $('#txtUsers').val() + '}',
   type: 'POST', // a jQuery ajax POST transmits in querystring format(key=value&key1=value1) in utf-8
   dataType: 'json', //return data in json format
   success: function (data) {
            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                return {
                    label: item.stateName,
                    value: item.name
                  //abbrev: item.stateAbbrev
                  };
             }));
         }
});
```

You have to declare your Service Cs class with **[ScriptService]** attribute

And If you use a Web Service for your server code instead of your user control's CS class you can write like this.

```
[ScriptService]
public class YourCSClass : System.Web.Services.WebService {
  [WebMethod]
  public static string GetNames(string Name)
  {
    return "";
  }
}
```

Comment: but i am using .ascx and want to make ajax call from this. you are using DietitianAppointment.aspx but i have .ascx.

Comment: You need to add your server side code to your ASPX page. Because a user control is just like a part of the main aspx page

Comment: This type of page is not served.

Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because it has been explicitly forbidden.     Please review the URL below and make sure that it is spelled correctly.